# I want create an web app with webview but it cant load json file

Tags: android, webview, android-webview

I want to create an application for website by use `webview`  but putting all files of website in asset folder when i load it like below code it cant open `json.data` files and cant show any thing in `json` file ! what should i do ?

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
WebView htmlWebView ;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

   htmlWebView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView);
    WebSettings webSetting = htmlWebView.getSettings();
    webSetting.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webSetting.setDisplayZoomControls(true);
  // htmlWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/piping/index.html");
   htmlWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/enzo/index.html");
   // htmlWebView.loadUrl("http://www.enzo.cafe");
    htmlWebView.setWebViewClient(new MyAppWebViewClient());
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if(htmlWebView.canGoBack()) {
        htmlWebView.goBack();
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
```

Comment: why are you putting files in assets if  your website is live ?

Comment: whats difference ? its a way

Comment: Is any way for my code that can open json files ?

Comment: link of mysite is http://www.enzo.cafe when  i use  this solution it cant show pictures of   
   گالری تصاویر  that they introduce in json file

Answer (score 0):

I've successfully run  this code . So  try With this.

```
        htmlWebView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView);
        WebSettings webSetting = htmlWebView.getSettings();
        webSetting.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webSetting.setDisplayZoomControls(true);
        htmlWebView.loadUrl("http://www.enzo.cafe");
        htmlWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {

            @Override
            public boolean onJsAlert(WebView view, String url, String message,
                                     JsResult result) {

                return super.onJsAlert(view, url, message, result);
            }

        });
```

Comment: i want load index.html in webview .. it load in chrome but cant show any thing in webview ? it have this errors                                             E/Zygote: v2
? E/Zygote: accessInfo : 0
 E/libEGL: validate_display:255 error 3008 (EGL_BAD_DISPLAY)
E/File: fail readDirectory() errno=2